# What is an example of conjugate, non-equal subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can you suggest to me an example of two non-abelian subgroups of a group which are conjugate?

And are all abelian subgroups are self conjugate?

I mean if $H$ is an abelian subgroup of a group $G$, then does $g^{-1} H g = H$ hold for all $g\in G$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example:

Let $G=S_3$, $H_1=\{(1),(12)\}$, $g_1=(13)$, $g_2=(23)$, then
$$g_1^{-1}H_1g_1= \{(1),(23)\} \neq H_1$$
$$g_2^{-1}H_1g_2= \{(1),(13)\} \neq H_1$$

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure that I understand what you are looking for.

First: If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $g^{-1}Hg = H$ for all $g\in G$. So for an example you can pick your favorite normal subgroup of a non-abelian group. Concretely, you could consider the [normal subgroups of the symmetric groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group#Normal_subgroups).

And yes, if $G$ is abelian, then all subgroups (including $G$) is "self-conjugate".

If you just want to see examples of conjugates of subgroups, I suggest (again) to look the subgroups of the symmetric groups.

Comment: g^{-1} H_1 g = H_2 , iff H_1 and H_2 are conjugate, am in need of different H_1 and H_2

Comment: @user125245: I don't understand.

Comment: I need a typical example for conjugate subgroups..

Comment: @user125245: So you want an example of a group $H_1$ and $H_2$ such that $g H_1 g^{-1} = H_2$ for all or just for some $g$?

Comment: ya, but H_1 and H_2 should different, for some g

Comment: @user125245: So just take a subgroup of a symmetric group and conjugate it with some element.

Answer (score 1):

Going from your comments to Thomas' answer, you are looking for two (abelian) subgroups $H_1, H_2\leq G$ such that $H_1\neq H_2$ and there exists some $g\in G$ such that $gH_1g^{-1}=H_2$.

A general formula (sort of) exists for finding such a triple $(H_1, H_2, G)$, and it is as follows:

1. Begin with your favourite non-abelian group $G$, for example the dihedral group with $8$ elements $D_4$ (sometimes called $D_8$), which is the group of symmetries of the square. So $G=D_4$.
2. Find an (abelian) subgroup $H_1$ of $G$ which is not normal, for example the subgroup $\{1, \text{flip}\}\leq D_4$.
3. Now, because $H_1$ is not normal there exists an element $g\in G$ such that $gH_1g^{-1}\neq H_1$. Find such an element $g$. In our example, $g=\text{rotate}90^{\circ}$ works.
4. Write $H_2=gH_1g^{-1}$, and this is the triple you are after! In our example, $H_1=\{1, \text{flip}\}\neq \{1, \text{rotate}90^{\circ}\text{ flip rotate} 270^{\circ}\}=H_2$, but they are conjugate.

There are some points to look out for when doing this. The first one is that the element $g$ must be chosen carefully. Clearly, you want to choose $g$ such that $g\not\in H_1$, but it is slightly more complicated than that. For example, let $G=A_6$. Note that $A_6$ is simple and not cyclic, so we can take $H_1$ to be *any* non-trivial subgroup. Let us take $H_1=\{1, (123), (132)\}$. Then (which is the point of this example) we have to be careful in picking the conjugator $g$. There does exist an element $g\in G$ such that $gH_1g^{-1}\neq H_1$, but it does not work for all $g\in G$. For example, $g=(456)$ *does not work* (why?). However, taking $g=(12)(34)$ *does* work. The key word is *[normaliser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliser)* - you want to pick $g$ such that it is not contained in the *normaliser* of $H_1$, $g\not\in N_G(H_1)$.

The second point to look out for is that the group $G$ matters. You already know that you need to pick $G$ to be non-abelian, but that isn't enough. For example, the [Quaternion group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group) $Q_8$ is non-abelian and simple of order $8$, and *all its subgroups are normal*. So you can never pick $G$ in the triple to be $Q_8$.